Long text replacement with % sign in it and finishing with commands
When typing #=- and pressing space, I would like Autohotkey to text replace that text with the text shown below:
#%%=============================================================================
# 
#%===============================================================================

I would also like for the cursor to end in the middle of the two lines (line 2).
My first attempt looked like this:
:O:#=-::#%%============================================================================={enter}#{space}{enter}#%==============================================================================={up 1}

But this would not work, and instead Authotkey would open some random app on my computer. (How is this even possible?)
My second attempt was to write a continuation/long text replacement, like shown below:
:O:#=-::
(
#%%=============================================================================
# 
#%===============================================================================
)

This works, but my cursor does not end in the middle.
I tried adding {up 1} at the end like shown below, but authotkey ignores the command and writes literally {up 1}.
:O:#=-::
(
#%%=============================================================================
# 
#%===============================================================================
){end 1}

I also tried to use Send, but I cannot make Autohotkey then ignore the percentage signs.
Can anyone help me out with this?

For long text replacements i'd use the clipboard, as in  this answer. The percent signs in the text have to be escaped.

I found how to make my text replacement work. It turns out that both the symbols % and # Autohotkey was recognising as commands. To make Autohotkey ignore these symbols, the percentage sign needs to be escaped with `%, and the hashtag needs to be in curly brackets, i.e. {#}.
Therefore a working text replacement method would be:
:O:#%=-::{#}`%`%============================================================================{enter}{#}{space}{enter}{#}`%============================================================================={up 1}

I like this because it is a oneliner.
However as @Relax points out, long text replacements are done faster using the clipboard method, as explained in this answer.
